# Compressed output of set in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

In order to provide a better output of sets with many consecutive elements (a similar class could be written for a `list` or `tuple`, but in this case I stay with a `set`), I wrote the following class, derived from a `set`.
However, some inspiration has been found in the `itertools` and `operator` package documentation.
I'm using the code to output ports assigned to a *device under test* in a test system.

```py
import itertools
import operator


class PrettySet(set[int]):
    """ Subclassed set which redefines __str__ operator so that consecutive elements are compressed in the
        formatted string """
    @staticmethod
    def _seg_to_str(segment: list):
        return f"{segment[0]}..{segment[-1]}" if len(segment) > 2 else ", ".join(map(str, segment))
    def __str__(self):
        groups = itertools.groupby(enumerate(sorted(self)), lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
        segments = [list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), g)) for _, g in groups]
        return "{" + ", ".join(map(self._seg_to_str, segments)) + "}"
```

Example output:

```
> data = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
> print(PrettySet(data))

> {1..3, 6..8, 10, 11, 14..16, 18, 20..25}
```

Please review my code in terms of

- readability
- usability
- size

What would you do differently?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## Stop Writing Classes

See [Stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) by Jack Diederich.  Short summary: if you instantiate a class, use the class once, and then throw it away, (eg, `print(PrettySet(data))`) you should just write a function.

```
def pretty_set(data: set[int]) -> str:
    """Create a string representation of a set of integers, with the integers
    in increasing order, and consecutive integers represented by a start value,
    two dots, and the end value.

    >>> pretty_set({1, 5, 12, 2, 3, 13, 6, 7})
    '{1..3, 5..7, 12, 13}'
    """
 
    ... implementation here ...
```

## Minor nit

The empty set will return the string `{}` which appears to be an empty dictionary, not an empty set.

## Readability

Your code needs blank lines before method definitions.

You need to use type hints consistently.  In `def _seg_to_str(segment: list):`, segment should be `list[int]`, and the return type should be `-> str`.

`groups = itertools.groupby(enumerate(sorted(self)), lambda x: x[1] - x[0])` is very dense and opaque.  It returns something like `((1, [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]), (3, [(3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 8)]), (4, [(6, 10), (7, 11)]), (6, [(8, 14), (9, 15), (10, 16)]), (7, [(11, 18)]), (8, [(12, 20), (13, 21), (14, 22), (15, 23), (16, 24), (17, 25)]))`, which is an iterable of tuples of an int and a list of tuples of two ints.  No comment in sight as to what those mean, so maintainability is low.

Next, you have `[list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), g)) for _, g in groups]`, which is making a nested list of lists ... plus `for _, g in groups` is extracting the second item of elements of groups, and `operator.itemgetter(1)` is **also** extracting the second item of *something*.  Again, no comment in sight.

## Different implementation

The `segments = [list(...) for ...]` statement could be turned into a generator to prevent unnecessary construction of the outer loop, but the inner lists all get unnecessarily created.  A lighter weight implementation   could be made with a function that takes elements one-at-a-time, collect sequential elements, and `yield` string of either single elements or ranges.  No tuples or lists need to be constructed.

Perhaps:

```
def pretty_set(data: set[int]) -> str:
    """Create a string representation of a set of integers, with the integers
    in increasing order, and consecutive integers represented by a start value,
    two dots, and the end value.

    >>> pretty_set({1, 5, 12, 2, 3, 13, 6, 7})
    '{1..3, 5..7, 12, 13}'
    """
    
    def segments():
        it = iter(sorted(data))
        start = end = next(it)
        for item in it:
            if item == end + 1:
                end = item
            else:
                if end > start + 1:
                    yield f"{start}..{end}"
                else:
                    yield str(start)
                    if start != end:
                        yield str(end)

                start = item
                end = item

        if end > start + 1:
            yield f"{start}..{end}"
        else:
            yield str(start)
            if start != end:
                yield str(end)

    if len(data) < 2:
        return str(data)
    
    return "{" + ", ".join(segments()) + "}"
            
data = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
print(pretty_set(data))
```

It is longer, but perhaps it might be more understandable, and possibly a little more efficient.

Comment: When I first saw the original code I also thought this was yet another class that should actually be just a function. But in this case I see a real benefit of the class because you can pass the `PrettySet` instance around and it will pretty print everywhere it is printed.

Comment: The actual usecase of this class is to be used as a `set`. However, I needed some improved output for logging purposes to prevent sth like: `WARNING:root:Something happened on ports {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ..., 20}`. Therefor, I replaced the original `set` containing a subset of ports by the `PrettySet` class. This way I can log failing ports without thinking about output format on each and every `logger.warning(f"blabla {failing_ports}")`. I also watched the video, which makes some good points, but I think it's biased as it misses any discussion of the drawbacks of the procedural approach.

Comment: @LooserUser Based on the usage shown in the question as posted, with `print(PrettySet(data))`, the "Stop Writing Classes" feedback is correct.  In future questions, post all relevant code (ie, both the utility and usages of the utility) to get feedback relevant to your real question instead of a toy example.

Comment: I'm still not completely decided whether I use the _class_ or the _proc_ approach. I's not that I object the _proc_ approach. It's just that I was confronted very often with repetitive code which spreads pod's and dict accesses all over and I wished people used more type sane and reusable code being it a set of classes or even procedures. Anyway, there's a drawback in my derived class I didn't see before. The `intersection`, `union` and such do not work as expected, returning the original `set` instead of the `PrettySet`. A proc would free me from the need to implement those overloads.

Answer (score 2):

### Useability

I think your code does a good job at outputting the information in a readable
and concise way. I also see potential for reuseability in other code.

In my opinion, contrary to AJNeufeld's answer it also makes sense for the pretty set to be a class instead of a function because this enables you to pass a `PrettySet` around and have it pretty printed everywhere.

### Typing

As AJNeufeld already pointed out in their answer there are some issues with your type annotations.

What I would like to add here is that the type checker `mypy` can detect these errors *if you run it in strict mode*:

```bash
$ mypy --strict pretty_set.py
pretty_set.py:37: error: Function is missing a return type annotation
pretty_set.py:37: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "list"
pretty_set.py:39: error: Function is missing a type annotation
Fund 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

### Readability

I strongly agree with AJNeufeld's answer that the first two lines of your `__str__` methods where the `groups` and `segments` are constructed are hard to understand.

I would suggest to use `itertools.pairwise` instead to compare each element with its predecessor. This can then be used to check if the elements are consecutive or not.

```py
import itertools


class PrettySet(set[int]):
    """Subclassed set which redefines __str__ operator so that consecutive
    elements are compressed in the formatted string"""

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """Create a string representation of the set.

        Consecutive values are compressed, for example {1, 3, 4, 5, 7}
        is formatted as {1, 3..5, 7}.
        """

        parts: list[str] = []
        if self:

            def make_string(start: int, prev: int) -> str:
                return f"{prev}" if start == prev else f"{start}..{prev}"

            ordered = sorted(self)
            start = ordered[0]
            for prev, elem in itertools.pairwise(ordered):
                if elem - prev > 1:
                    parts.append(make_string(start, prev))
                    start = elem
            parts.append(make_string(start, ordered[-1]))

        return f"{{{', '.join(parts)}}}"
```

I think this code is easier to understand but I may have a bias because I wrote it.

I am also not sure if I find `return f"{{{', '.join(parts)}}}"` or `return "{" + ", ".join(parts) + "}"` more readble.

### Size

I do not know what exactly you mean by reviewing the code with regard to "size", but I don't think number of characters, number of bytes, number of lines or anything like that is relevant in this case.

Comment: `prev is not None` is always true, so redundant.  The assignment to `prev` is overwritten by the next iteration of the `for prev, elem …` loop, so is meaningless, and can be removed.

Comment: You are right, these are artifacts from an earlier stage when I did not use `itertools.pairwise`. I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: For completeness, you might add a `from_compressed()` class method to reconstruct a set from the compressed string.

Comment: @RootTwo Haha, I would like that as an exersize.

Comment: I started to look how I could implement the suggestions given in this thread. When I implemented my `PrettySet` class I dealt with `int` `set`'s. However, now I think a type hint like `set[Ordered]` would be more appropriate, so a set using complex numbers as keys would not suffice. I've seen some suggestions, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669222/how-can-i-hint-that-a-type-is-comparable-with-typing. However, it would add more boilerplate code for little benefit. So I would perhaps stay with `class PrettySet(set)`???

Comment: I also tried to make the `PrettySet` class more generic, but I think the problem is that you not only need an order of the elements but also the idea of successor/predecessor to create a range. I think this would also work well with chars, but I don't think a really generic version of the `PrettySet` is possible. How would your expected output look for a given input when the elements of the set are complex numbers?

Comment: _> How would your expected output look for a given input when the elements of the set are complex numbers?_ That was just given as a counter example.
I see your point. `PrettySet(set[float])` would not make much sense, imho. Only given discrete keys, this class may be of any use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my new implementation which adresses the following issues as suggested by AJNeufeld and M472. I just wanted to share this code. *I'm not posting just to accept my own answer as a solution.*

1. Readability: Using `itertools.groupby` is hard to read, therefore using `itertools.pairwise`
2. The custom `set` was implemented as a `class` called `PrettySet` so it can be used as a `set` and being passed around. However, the methods which should produce new `PrettySet`'s from a combination or copy return `set`s instead. This surprising behaviour contradicts the original justification for writing a class. Therefore, the `class` has been replaced by a `function` which takes a normal `set[int]` as input. The overhead of implementing all those necessary overloads cannot be justified.
3. The code sections were properly separated by empty lines.
4. Intermediate creation of data structures (e.g. nested lists) has been avoided in order to format the string directly. This addresses memory usage and performance.
5. The corner case for formatting an empty set is solved by returning a string which cannot be confused with a dict.
6. Type issues have been checked using `mypy`.
7. The original implementation compressed a section of consecutive elements of length 3 and up. This was considered an implementation detail and was not taken into account here.

```
import itertools


def pretty_format_set(src_set: set[int]) -> str:
    """ Formats a set into a comma separated string compressing consecutive elements, for example
        {1, 3, 4, 5, 7} is formatted as {1, 3..5, 7}. """

    def make_string(range_start: int, range_end: int) -> str:
        """ Returns a string representation of an integer range, compressing consecutive values """
        return f"{range_start}" + ("" if range_start == range_end else f"..{range_end}")

    if src_set:
        formatted_str = "{"
        ordered = sorted(src_set)
        start = ordered[0]

        # Iterate over the src_set to find consecutive elements and format string on the fly
        for prev, elem in itertools.pairwise(ordered):
            if elem - prev > 1:
                formatted_str += make_string(start, prev) + ", "
                start = elem
        else:
            # Terminate the output after the last loop iteration
            formatted_str += make_string(start, ordered[-1]) + "}"

        return formatted_str

    return "{*[]}"
```

Usage:

```
test_array: list[set[int]] = [{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4},
                              {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {*[]}]

for data in test_array:
    print(pretty_format_set(data))
```

Output:

```
{1}
{1..2}
{1..3}
{1, 3}
{1..2, 4}
{1, 3..4}
{1..3, 6..8, 10..11, 14..16, 18, 20..25}
{*[]}
```

Type check:

```bash
user@l-user:~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches$ python3 -m mypy --strict pretty_print_set2.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```